# Best Way to search for a string containing a letter or a word in SQL Server (Full Contains Search)

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, full-text-search

I have a requirement where I need to search a few columns in the table to see if the letter or word passed in as parameter is contained in any of those columns and return the first 100 rows. For example:

```
select id, col1, col2, col3
from table
where col1 like '%word%'
or col2 like '%word%'
or col3 like '%word%'
order by col1
offset 50 rows 
fetch next 100 rows only
```

I know that using a % as the beginning and end of a like operation will result in index scan. Is there a better way to write these kinds of queries? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a "*full contains*" type of search? As it's much easier to optimize a check for "*starts with or ends with*". E.g. '%this' or 'this%' is easier to optimize than '%this%'.

Comment: @J.D. It has to be a full contains type of search, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem! There are other solutions for full contains search. They're just more involved.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'm looking forward to the solutions.

Comment: Try a search for sql server & trigrams